# The best OS X for late 2008 MacBook?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

What's the latest supported OS X for the 1181 model?

Also what is the best version (performance and speed wise) for the model?

Comment: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1593194

Answer (score 3):

Maximum OS for A1181 is 10.7.5 (Lion)

That is going to be the best option performance wise.